# How to set submit button using javascript confirm box?

Tags: javascript, php

Is is possible to trigger the button type `"submit"` on my confirm box using javascript? I wanted to trigger the submit button on my `"OK"` option. I wanted to remove the `<button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">Okay!</button>` in my HTML form. I just wanted to trigger it under `"OK"` option is this possible?

**Javascript**

```
<script>

    function showApprove()
    {
        value = confirm("Approve this document?");
        if (value == true)
        {
            // I WANTED TO TRIGGER HERE :)
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    function showReject()
    {
        value = confirm("Reject this document?");
        if (value == true)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

</script>
```

**View**

```
<input type="hidden" name = "id" value = "{{$list->id}}">

<div class = "radio">
    <label><input type = "radio" onclick = "showApprove()" name = "status" id = "approve" value="1"> Approve</label>
</div>


<div class = "radio">
    <label><input type = "radio" onclick = "showReject()" name = "status" id = "reject" value="0"> Reject</label>
</div>

<button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">Okay!</button>

<input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "{{ Session::token() }}">
```

So my View looks like there's no button anymore in my HTML. I just wanted to trigger this in my confirm box.

Comment: what is the issue...your code seems fine and i think it will work..please explain the questions output you want

Answer (score 0):

Call the [`submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) method on the form element to trigger a submit event

```
document.querySelector(".form-line").submit();
```

Comment: @Francisunoxx, then remove the `<button>`. You would still call the `.submit()` method on the form element to submit it

Comment: after removing `<button>` where should I trigger the submit?

Comment: @Francisunoxx, where ever you need to, since you say you want it triggered on hitting _"OK"_ do it in your if statement `if (value == true){}`

Answer (score 0):

Call the submit function, add an id to your form id="myForm"

```
 document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit your form from javascript as :

```
function showApprove()
{
    value = confirm("Approve this document?");
    if (value == true)
    {
        document.getElementById("formId").submit();//please set id attribute to your form.
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

You can follow this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp).

Answer (score 0):

the .submit() answers are right they will submit the form, but if you need to click the buttonand not submit form for some reason using javascript (like , you need the button value or something) use the following code

**HTML**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="okbutton" >Okay!</button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function showApprove()
{
    value = confirm("Approve this document?");
    if (value == true)
    {
        document.getElementById("okbutton").click();
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: No. I wanted to remove my `<button>` in my form and trigger the submit upon hitting the `"Ok"` option. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

> Change :

```
 <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">Okay!</button>
```

> To :

```
 <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary">Okay!</button>
```

> Then :

```
<script>
        function showApprove()
        {
            if(confirm("Approve this document?"))
            {
                 document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

    </script>
```